# Problema de Cast num método genérico que recebe um array de enum's (enum[])

Tags: c#, enums, genéricos

Pretendo fazer um método genérico que recebe um `enum[]` e que retorne uma *string* representando os itens do *array* separados por virgula.

```
public static string ToSeparatedCommaString<T>(T[] enums)
    where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible//Não garante que seja enum mas sempre limita alguma coisa
{
    var commaString = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in enums)
    {
        commaString += ((Enum)item).GetStringValue() + ",";
    }
    return commaString.TrimEnd(',');
}
```

O problema surge quando quero aceder ao *Extension Method* `GetStringValue()`.
A tentativa de fazer ***cast***, como era de esperar, não é permitida.

Há alguma forma de conseguir isto?

<sub>`GetStringValue()` é um método que retorna uma *string* cujo valor é o indicado no atributo associado ao elemento do `enum`</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma forma fácil de resolver o problema é fazer o *box* do `item` em um `object` e depois dar outro cast para o tipo final `Enum`.

Mais algumas sugestões:

- testar o tipo de `T` para garantir que este seja um tipo de enum, e lançar uma exceção descritiva do problema que ocorreu caso não seja
- usar LINQ faz o código mais fácil (eu acho, é apenas uma sugestão)

  ```
  return string.Join(",", enums.OfType<Enum>().Select(item => item.GetStringValue()));
  ```

  Como disse que `GetStringValue` é método de extensão, dá pra fazer assim também:

  ```
  return string.Join(",", enums.OfType<Enum>().Select(NomeDaClasse.GetStringValue));
  ```

Código final... sem usar LINQ pois isso é questão de estilo e é pessoal:

```
public static string ToSeparatedCommaString<T>(T[] enums)
    where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        throw new Exception("O método de extensão `ToSeparatedCommaString` suporta apenas Enums no parâmetro genérico `T`.");

    var commaString = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in enums)
    {
        commaString += ((Enum)(object)item).GetStringValue() + ",";
    }
    return commaString.TrimEnd(',');
}
```

Comment: O que é método de extensão é `GetStringValue()`. O controlo do erro era para ser adicionado depois. Neste caso não faz muito sentido ser método de extensão porque só se aplica a `enum[]`.

Comment: Não há como garantir que o tipo `T` seja enum. Então a garantia tem de ser via código.

Comment: Entendo... mas mesmo que não seja método de extensão, ainda assim é bom verificar que o tipo `T` realmente seja `Enum`, pois se não for, vai ocorrer uma exceção ao fazer o type-cast para `Enum`.

Comment: Claro, como eu disse acima, estava previsto ser feita essa verificação.

Comment: Eu andava a pesquisar uma solução que utilizava `Enum.ToObject()` mas a sua solução é mais simples. Só me fica a pergunta do porquê da existência do método `Enum.ToObject()` se o simples *cast* para *object* funciona.

Comment: O `Enum.ToObject` serve para converter um inteiro em um `Enum` dado o `Type` desse enum: `Enum.ToObject(typeof(MeuEnum), 123)`. O retorno já sai boxed com o tipo `object`. Esse método existe pois nem sempre vai se ter o tipo do enum estaticamente, somente um objeto Type.

Comment: Dei uma melhorada na versão LINQ para ficar mais legível.

Comment: O LINK é mais legível para quem o domina bem, o que ainda não é o meu caso!

Comment: Eu fiz o teste do @bigown na versão LINQ... ela é claramente a mais horrível dentre todas... 3,5x mais lenta. Então fique a vontade em não usar LINQ!

Answer (score 3):

Você sabe que sem dar a garantia, não dá para ter um código confiável, então vai ter que resolver em tempo de execução se é possível fazer a operação ou não. Tem algumas formas possíveis, algumas melhores que outras, algumas te darão mais poder de como manipular o erro, se ele ocorrer. Pode fazer isto:

```
public static string ToSeparatedCommaString<T>(T[] enums)
    where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible {
    var commaString = string.Empty;
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) {
        throw new ArgumentException("Tipo de enums é inválido");
    }
    foreach (var item in enums) {
        Enum enumerador = item as Enum;
        commaString += enumerador.GetStringValue() + ",";
    }
    return commaString.TrimEnd(',');
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jsOp4X). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NTDN8N). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/CommaGenerated.cs).

Fiz uma [comparação de performance](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vhmBjd) da abordagem que eu propus com a da resposta do Miguel que resolve bem também. O resultado desta foi melhor. Isto foi debatido nos comentários abaixo.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54239/discussion-on-answer-by-bigown-problema-de-cast-num-metodo-generico-que-recebe-u)